# In which non-gorenstein algebras, are all maximal ideals  Gorenstein injective modules? 

Tags: homological-algebra, rt.representation-theory

In which non-gorenstein algebras, are all maximal ideals  Gorenstein injective modules?

or Are the Gorenstein injective dimensions of all maximal ideals finite?